# Give a data structure that you can initialize in O(n) given n key pairs with values in [1,n^3] , and find all pairs where left value is a in O(logn)

Tags: data-structures, computer-science

Give a data structure that you can initialize in O(n) given n key pairs with values in [1,n^3] , and find all pairs where left value is a in O(logn)
(space complexity should be O(n))

I got this problem in data structures course, the first part was to to it for range [1,10n] and O(1) for find complexity which was a lot easier.
I tried a few structures but nothing seems to work in the complexity needed.
If I just insert all to array then I can't get what i need in O(logn) so I don't think this is the right way.
Trees also seems to not be helpful as that can't initialize in time needed.

Would really appreciate some guidance in the right way without giving the answer itself if possible

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by “all pairs where left value is a?” I’m not sure I understand the problem.

Comment: we are given n pairs (a1,b1),..,(an,bn) and need to return all the pairs where the left value equal to a(given in a function)

Comment: Is this even possible? If there are more than logarithmically many pairs with that first value, you can’t return all of them in logarithmic time.

Comment: I guess I will need to make the structure initialize in a way it will be possible,  with saving it as a linked list or something(that is how I did the first part), but I don't see how to do it

Comment: would a binary heap still initialize in O(n) if I save linked list in every element and add to the same place ones with the same ai? That is the only thing I could think of

Comment: How does a hash map not solve this problem? The key is the left value, and the value is a list of right values. You can return the list of values in O(1). Actually enumerating the values, though, will take O(k) (where k is the number of values).

Comment: @IdanDaniel The problem with a binary heap is that it takes O(n) to find an item. Your heap initialization would be O(n^2) because for each item you'd have to search the entire list to determine if that a-value had already been entered. And your final search would be O(n), as well. You could speed that up by using a hash map or dictionary to keep track of the items you've already added, but then what do you need the heap for? Just use the hash map.

Comment: @Jim Mischel I thought about it but what exactly will be the array we are hashing into? It will need to have O(n) space complexity, I do not think it follow all the complexities I need

Comment: @IdanDaniel Expected storage for a hash table, assuming you have a good hashing function, is O(n). Adding an item to the hash table is O(1). Adding an item to the list indexed by a particular key is O(1). Retrieving an item by key is O(1). What complexities does the hash table not satisfy?

Comment: It will have to be a perfect hash though to return exactly what I search for

Answer (score 0):

A sorted array of pairs works fine.  Since values are <= n<sup>3</sup>, you can use radix sort to sort them in O(n) time and O(n) space.  The find all pairs with a specific first value, you can do two binary searches to find the start and end positions of that list in the array.

Comment: How is redix sort O(n)? it will work in O(n^3) in the given range. It will only run in O(n) for a range of fixed number and it isn't

Comment: LSB-first radix sort will take, for example, 3 passes with N buckets.  That's O(n)

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something bu there is no way it will work in O(n). radix sort works in O(d(n+R)) where d is number of digits of numbers I sort each between 0 and R-1=N^3-1 so complexity is O(n^3). It seems to my you say Rdix sort will always run in O(n) which Isn't true

Comment: Numbers from **0** to **n^3** take **3** digits in radix **n+1**, so **d(n+R) = 3(n+n+1)**, which is **O(n)**